# Need static menu when overflow-x:scroll

Tags: css-position

I have four inline images that will extend the width of my mobile browser.  Below them, on the left margin, I have a menu with internal links to each image.  This all works and clicking on the fourth link will scroll the viewport to the farthest right image.

I would like the menu to stay planted on the left margin but it scrolls off the screen, following the left margin. I have tried position:fixed and absolute but it won't stay fixed like when using fixed scrolling up and down.

```
    <style>
    img {border:blue solid thin; width:100%;  }

    .scroller {display:inline; max-width:180px;  white-space:nowrap; 
    text-align:left; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">

    <div class="scroller" style="">
    <div style="display:inline-block; height:300px; border:red solid thin;">
         <img src="car_1.gif" id="1" >
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; height:300px; border:red solid thin;">
        <img src="car_2.gif" id="2">
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; height:300px; border:red solid thin;">
         <img src="car_3.gif" id="3">
    </div>
    </div>

   <div style="position:absolute; top:330px; left:0; padding:20px; 
    border:solid green thin;">
       <a href="#1">one</a>
       <a href="#2">two</a>
       <a href="#3">three</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post some code please. It's kinda hard to visualise it all in my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position:fixed or position absolute
Then menu will be static it wont move.

Comment: i am not getting please attach screenshoots before and after then i will try